# Why is my error not being caught and handled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
  message.guild.emojis.create(emoteLink, emoteName, {reason: `emote created by ${message.author.tag} thru command line`}).catch(error => {
    if (error.code == 50035) {
      return message.reply(toobigEmbed);
    } else if(error.code == 30018) {
      return message.reply(toomany1Embed);
    } else if(error.code == 30008){
      return message.reply(toomany2Embed);
    } else {
      message.reply("unknown error, i have no clue what happened");
      return message.channel.send("<@176610715686273024>")
    }
  })
```

Discord.js V12
It's as simple as the the title, basically what is happening is that in the case of an error occuring, it would caught the message and respond with a specific one based on the error code.

The issue is that the code is simply not catching it at all and not firing up a response.

This was working perfectly, I have no clue what happened and why this is happening as I have no touched it since I initially completed this.

Full code: https://hastebin.com/semokuhipi.typescript

Comment: Do you know that the .catch handler is triggering?

Comment: It used to be triggering, it's doesn't seem to be triggering anymore